# WHAT ARE THE SPECIFIC SYMPTOMS OF BURN TRANSMISSION

Tags: transmission

I BEING TOLD THAT MY TRANSMISSION BURN IT WAS RUNING PERFECTLY AND SUDLENLY I WASNT ABLE TO SPEED MORE THAN 20MPH BUT STILL RUNS IM NOT SURE IF IS TRUTH SINCE FIRTS THEY SAID ALL I NEED TO DO WAS A TUNE UP FOR IT

Comment: Welcome to SE Mechanics! In order to help specifics of your situation are usually needed. Can you tell us the vehicle involved (make, model, year), how many miles it has on it. What you know about its physical condition (especially how much fluid is in the transmission and its condition – color, what does it smell like). All of those will help. Also, avoid all caps if you can. It is hard to read and comes across as shouting.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a "burnt up" transmission, you are likely to see that your transmission fluid is a very dark color instead of pink, and may feel gritty if you rub it between your fingers, and may also have a "burnt" smell if you smell it.

Answer (score 1):

If one of your auto transmission clutches is burnt, then the clutch will not be working, therefore at least one of your 'gears' will not work.  A symptom would be that your engine would rev high, but you wouldn't be able to go any faster.  Being limited to 20 MPH certainly sounds like a it could be a burnt clutch.  @Robert S. Barnes is correct that the transmission fluid will also be dirty with clutch lining.